# Better representation of perf data. Filter functions?

Tags: function, filter, perf

I have some problems with my illustration of the function.
Can someone tell me how to get a representation where I can see which function is using how much time?

But these should only be functions from my (board pilot).
Kernel calls should not be deepened.

So I want to see which function from my program uses the most time to analyze and improve it later.

In my "output tree" this is already marked with (k) and (.).
Are there perhaps filter functions for this in a flamegraph or is it already possible to filter perf so that I only see the functions from my program?

Thanks for your help!
:)

Answer (score 2):

About ignoring the kernel calls, I suggest you to run perf without sudo, or run it monitoring only cycles in userspace like in the following example:

```
perf record -g -e cycles:u ls
```

Have a look at the man pages of `perf list` to understand how to use the event modifiers properly.

**EDIT**

**Starting from Linux 4.6**, as suggested by [PeterCordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes), you can just add the `--all-user` option to the `perf` command to collect all the selected events in user space (The default even selected for `perf record` is `cycles`).

Comment: An alternative to the `:u` modifier is `perf record --all-user` to effectively apply that to every event you're recording.  Handy if you have a list of multiple events (like you normally would for `perf stat`, which this works with as well.)

Comment: I have tried the following:

perf record -a -g -p PID > perf.data
perf script -i perf.data > profile.linux-perf.txt
perf record -a -o /root/perf.data -g -p PID

Hereby I load my file directly into https://www.speedscope.app/

I copy the file profile.linux-perf.txt over. 

But I get an output with (k) and (.) outputs.
Can this be filtered? Or where do I start or what do I have to change in the commands so that I only get the functions from my program?

Comment: As @PeterCordes pointed out, try to add `--all-user` option to the first `perf record` command.

Comment: Where does --all-user have to be in perf record -a -g -p PID > perf.data ?

Comment: @shirl: like `perf record --all-user -a -g -p PID > perf.data`.  As an option to the `record` sub-command of `perf`, like all the other options you used.

Comment: @PeterCordes when I type this the following appears: Error: Unknown option 'all-user'

Comment: @shirl: I think that option was added fairly recently.  I'm on Arch GNU/Linux with kernel 5.7.6, perf version 5.7.g3d77e6a8804a.  If you can update your `perf` version conveniently, do it.  Otherwise, specify an event explicitly with `-e cycles:u` or whatever.  (I think the default for `record` is `-e cycles`).

Comment: @shirl It seems it was introduced in Linux 4.6 in 2016: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/85723885feb823b4fc352b727ece0b6d00306c4d

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I have an older version. 
With  **-e cycles** I don't get what I want either. 

In the end I only want to see a time load of certain functions. 
For example of: 
**io_digital_transfer**
**io_digital_copier**

**io_hid_transfer**
**io_hid_copier**


However, I have one more question. 
I find these functions in the display of speedscope.app 
However, I would like to have (only the functions I mentioned above) displayed. Can I export this and filter the selected functions collectively?

Comment: @shirl: I think you missed something skimming my last comment, and/or the last update to this answer.  Use `-e cycles:u`, not the default.  As far as filtering within userspace, I don't know.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don´t know exactly what to insert at **-e cycles:u**

Comment: @shirl: You don't insert anything else there, you just use it literally like shown in this answer for profiling `ls`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah allright. Thank you very very much!